# Cant store hashed password because of compare field

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, hash

So im trying to make a login system for my application and while the user is doing its registration i want him to write his password 2 times to comfirm that it is the right password. If i dont hash my users password after registration the registration runs smoothly but after hashing them i get an exeption while trying to save them in my sql database since (i think) they dont match anymore. How do i need to combat this issue?

**User Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TimeTrackerProject.Models
{
    [Table("Users")]
    public class Users
    {
        [Key]
        public int Iduser { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3]\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid email.")]
        public String Email { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Firstname is required")]
        public String Firstname { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Surname is required")]
        public String Surname { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public String Password { get; set; }
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Please confirm your password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public String ComfirmPassword { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Function is required")]
        public String Function { get; set; }
        public Boolean Active { get; set; }






        [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
        public virtual Roles role { get; set; }
        public int? RoleId { get; set; }


    }
}
```

**Crypto class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;


namespace TimeTrackerProject
{
    public static class Crypto
    {
        public static string Hash(string value)
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(
                System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value))
                );
        }
    }
}
```

**Register controller method**

```
  public ActionResult Register(Users account)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            account.Password = Crypto.Hash(account.Password);
            account.ComfirmPassword = Crypto.Hash(account.ComfirmPassword);
            using (TimeTrackerEntities db = new TimeTrackerEntities())
            {
                db.Users.Add(account);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            ModelState.Clear();
            ViewBag.Message = account.Firstname + " was successfully registered.";


        }
        return View();
    }
```

**EDIT:**
The exeption im getting is :System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities

Comment: **What** exception? Please [edit] your question to include the relevant information.

Comment: You do not have a `ComfirmPassword` property in your data model. That property goes in your view model only

Comment: Don't guess where the problem lies, read the exception. Also, [HMAC by itself is not a secure password hashing function](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29951/salted-hashes-vs-hmac). Also, you don't have to compare the hashed passwords, you can just compare the plaintext ones. Don't reinvent the authentication wheel, use secure, well-tested libraries.

Comment: Please read [ask], **read the exception** and do some research towards it. All you need to know is in the exception. Don't update your question with it before you did some research.

Comment: Why would you store both the `Password` and the `ComfirmPassword`  (whether hashed or not)? The compare operation is UI functionality, if the two match then you can store the single hash of that password. This also helps identify a possible second problem: *do not use database model objects for UI purposes*, use a *separate View model object* for the UI with many fields the same, but the View model object has 2 password fields and the database model object has just one.

Comment: Sorry it is my first time doing an registration page. What libraries do you recommend i use for this? And the exeption im getting is :System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities

Comment: [MVC Security, Authorization and Authentication](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security)

Comment: @PeterB im using code first migration to generate my databse so ComfirmPassword column was made automatically it has no special use. Do you think it is better for me to remove Comfirm password from my model class?

Comment: @StephenMuecke the problem with the link you sent me is that they are all using the integrated login system of visual studio and i was asked to make one myself for my assignment.

Comment: Then you have a good few weeks of research ahead of you before you will be ready to start writing the code :)

Comment: @PedroLopes With ASP.NET MVC, you often have to use a separate DTO (`ViewModel`) and database-Model in order to transfer data between the UI effectively. You should create your `User` model with the appropriate properties, then a `RegistrationDTO` with the `Password`/`Confirm Password`/etc that are required on registration, then transfer the data from the DTO to the Model.

Comment: @EBrown Oh i think i get what you are saying. So the best thing for me to do is to store the data from my registration field in a separate user model and transfer it to the my current model in the controller after the Modelstade validation is done?

Comment: @PedroLopes Yes. Use the DTO to display data to the UI and *transfer* it to the back-end.

Comment: @PedroLopes Please don't roll your own crypto. Use the built-in libraries for this...

Comment: When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 1):

You're using ASP.NET MVC wrong.

---

The model you're designing is a UI model - a `View Model`, a `Data-Transfer Object`. Take your pick: it fits this specific criteria:

- The model exists to present and obtain data from the user;
- The model **indirectly** represents database-level data;
- The model represents a **transfer** of data;

Generally in ASP.NET MVC we design things around the idea that the we use a `ViewModel`/`DTO` to transfer the data from the database to the user, or the other way around. The `ViewModel`/`DTO` can still have validation annotations, and can still do the same things as a regular model, but instead of transferring the model taken *from the UI* to the database directly, we'll put it in a **regular** `Model` that represents the actual database record.

If you look at the basic ASP.NET MVC template, you'll see this *exact practice* in action:

> ```
> public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
> {
> }
>
> public class RegisterViewModel
> {
>     [Required]
>     [EmailAddress]
>     [Display(Name = "Email")]
>     public string Email { get; set; }
>
>     [Required]
>     [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
>     [DataType(DataType.Password)]
>     [Display(Name = "Password")]
>     public string Password { get; set; }
>
>     [DataType(DataType.Password)]
>     [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
>     [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
>     public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
> }
>
> [HttpPost]
> [AllowAnonymous]
> [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
> public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
> {
>     if (ModelState.IsValid)
>     {
>         // Build an `ApplicationUser` (database model) out of the `RegisterViewModel`
>         var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
>         var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
>         if (result.Succeeded)
>         {
>             await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
>
>             return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
>         }
>         AddErrors(result);
>     }
>
>     // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
>     return View(model);
> }
> ```

So what we see here is that the designers built two models: an `ApplicationUser` (which is part of the `DbContext` and gets mapped to the database) and a `RegisterViewModel` (which is **not** part of the `DbContext`, and is just used to request data from the client).

Now this isn't *necessarily* intuitive, and a lot of the basic actions (like `Add` » `View`) get it wrong (they automatically add things to the `DbContext`) but this is the most effective way to manage it.

So in your case, you probably want to create the same structure: build a `User` model, then build a `RegisterViewModel` or `RegisterDTO` (the difference between `ViewModel` / `DTO` is one of convention only: `ViewModel` is self explanatory, and `DTO` is simply a 'Data Transfer Object').

---

As a free side-note: I often build `ViewModel`/`DTO` constructors that take the database model as a parameter and build themselves from it, you can do the same and go the other way around if necessary, or use some sort of 'mapper' (like ['Automapper'](http://automapper.org), for example) to manage the mapping from A » B for you.

Comment: wow thanks for the nice explanation i understand what i did wrong now. Will rework my code to implement this thank you!